# Login and download programmatically in Android

Tags: android

I want to make an application for a web page that needs POST login. After that I'll download an HTML page and read its tags and perform some tasks to display some information.

Before I begin, I want to know if there is a way login in to this page using POST, somehow programmatically and download the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a way to send post request:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com/login.php");
try
{
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "value"));          
    Httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

you can send your information in order to login to page.!

Comment: but I don't know where this webpage POST the data and what values does it read. Is it username & password or uname and pass etc... Or it does't matter?

Comment: the page is in the value of the String in the constructor of HttpPost that is here is `"http://www.example.com/login.php"` and the values that is read will not matter. You can name it as u like but you must accept it in the php page as the same name. Here I named it name and the value is "value". you can add another value like `nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "Khalid"));`
`nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "123456"));`

Comment: The website I want to make an application is this http://tinyurl.com/axy2u44 are you sure it is going to work? I don't of course own the site.

Comment: No it will not work because I Don't know the variable names that are sent to the website in order to login. If you know the variables that are sent to this website, you will be able to make this code.

Comment: as I checked, the code will be: `HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://www.wind.com.gr/gr/q/my-q-login/");` and you need to add the variable like `nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "YourName"));` and `nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "YourPassword"));` and I think it will work